# How do I Install graphic drivers for a radeon xpress200?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, radeon

I downloaded the drivers from [support.amd.com](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Legacy/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.7&product=2.7.4.3.3.3.1&lang=English),
but I can't figure out how to install them.

I have a monitor with a resolution of 1440x900 and **I'm trying to get the correct resolution to show up**. When I go to display settings only 1024x768 and 800x600 show up in the options.

I'm very new to Linux and am liking it so far, but this is the only problem I'm having... any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Lets get through some steps,

Read Manually installing Catalyst 12.4 section from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Alternatively in software center search for `fglrx`.. then install `ATI binary X.Org driver` from search result. This will install open source driver. This also works good.

Comment: I searched fglrx and installed ATI binary X.Org driver and restarted my computer.  It looks a little better, but it is only showing two more options for resolution.  It shows 800x600, 1024x768, 1152x864, and 1360x768.  Is there any way to manually add in 1440x900?